# Subsetting a data frame with dates as `str` and nan values in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame, extracted from a .csv file using `Data = pandas.read_csv`

One of the columns of the data frame are dates, such as `'14/09/2015'`, the type of data is `str`.

I need to create a subset, for which I use: `NewDataFrame = DataFrame['DatesColumn'][DataFrame['DatesColumn']==desired date]`

But I have two main problems:

1. Since the dates are strings, I have tried to use a slice [-1]. But I get the error: `KeyError : -1L`

I tried to use this code to select 2014:

`NewDataFrame = DataFrame['DatesColumn'][DataFrame['DatesColumn'][-1]==4]`

2. I have empty fields that have been imported as nan values. If I try to perform a `for` loop to transform the data, I get the error:

`TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

**Q: How can I subset the data (or clean it) by year?**

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `NaN` values you can use [`fillna()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

```
# to fill NaNs with zeros
noNans = withNans.fillna(0)
```

And for the date issue, 
instead of handling the date strings yourself you should let the already
existing libraries handle them for you. In this case the `read_csv()` function
can do it for you.
See the documentation
[here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Here's a little example:

Csv file:

```
1,14/09/2016,dataa
1,14/09/2015,dataa
2,14/10/2014,dataa2
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=None, parse_dates=[1])
df[df[1] > date.today()]
```

Prints only

```
   0          1      2
0  1 2016-09-14  dataa
```

Comment: It worked! The column was converted to "data type", and I could handle it with comparison operators. `nan` values were converted into NaT values, so I didn't have to deal with them. One thing still bothers me though. I tried the `.fillna()` method but it didn't work. The type of the nan values I get when pd.read_csv reads an empty field is `float`. Shouldn't it be numpy.float?